# Why android:showAsAction doesnt work and app:showAsAction does?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I've been stuck for a really long time with my app actions not showing as icons and finally I realized that some had the tag `app:showAsAction="always"` and some other had `android:showAsAction="always"`, but the ones who worked were those ones with the app prefix. Could somebody whats the reason for this to happen this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `appcompat-v7` action bar backport -- `ActionBarActivity` and kin -- are designed to work on devices going back to API Level 7. `android:showAsAction` was only added in API Level 11. Hence, `appcompat-v7` cannot readily use it. As a result, it defines its own custom menu attributes as replacements.

If you use the native action bar, you use `android:` attributes for everything. If you use `appcompat-v7`, you will use the `app:` attributes where needed and `android:` ones elsewhere.

Comment: You are great sir! I wonder how you find such answers, you also gave me answer to one of my tricky question.